# Capturing span error for a text box with selenium python

Tags: css, selenium, pytest

With the script below i am trying to get the error text from a span error text box for first name when a name is not entered and the user clicks on the submit button, from a registration screen with the HTML below.(https://www.walmart.com/account/signup. However I end up just getting none instead of the text. When i try to get the text from chrome console i receive the text with the xpath and css selector as "$x("//span[@class='span-error']")[2]" and "$$(".span-error")[2]". I would like some guidance as to what I am missing, i think have tried everything i can think of.

Test case:

- Get to the link Enter nothing on the first name,Get a validation
  error Assert the validation error Enter an invalid name as ":::" Get
  a validation error (they seem to have a couple)and so on

[image]

```
from time import sleep
from conftest import os
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


# LoginScreenSelectors
sel_first_name = "#first-name-su"
sel_last_name = "#last-name-su"
sel_email = "#email-su"
sel_password = "#password-su"
sel_error_message = ".span-error:nth-of-type(2)"
sel_submit = f"""[data-automation-id="signup-submit-btn"]"""
sel_required_error = f"""[data-error="required"]"""


class Login():
    '''This will signup to the applcaiton '''

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
        self.first_name = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_first_name))
        )
        self.last_name = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_last_name))
        )
        self.email = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_email))
        )
        self.password = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_password))
        )
        self.submit = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_submit))
        )

    def login_to_website(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        print(self.driver.title)
        self.first_name.click()
        self.first_name.send_keys("  ")
        self.first_name.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

        self.first_name_error_message = wait.until(
             EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_error_message))
         )
        type(self.first_name_error_message)
        error_messages = []
        for messages in self.first_name_error_message:
            print(error_messages.append(messages.text))

        #if i could get this then i could simply get the first index and then keep filtering
         it but even that is proving to be difficult.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this to get all elements with error messages

```
error_messages = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="sign-up-form"]/div/span[2]']")
```

Comment: Updated XPATH with a much better one, return 4 span elements with error messages

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving it.

Get the xpath as `f"""[data-error="required"]"""` and then with a for loop cycle through all the error messages for input fields, I hope this will help anyone that is trying to take a stab at validating happy and negative testing on the same testcase.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# LoginScreenSelectors
sel_first_name = "#first-name-su"
sel_last_name = "#last-name-su"
sel_email = "#email-su"
sel_password = "#password-su"
sel_submit = f"""[data-automation-id="signup-submit-btn"]"""
sel_required_error = f"""[data-error="required"]"""

class Register():
'''This wil register the user to the application '''

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
    self.first_name = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_first_name))
    )
    self.last_name = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_last_name))
    )
    self.email = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_email))
    )
    self.password = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_password))
    )
    self.submit = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_submit))
    )

def login_to_website(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    '''This will check for validaitons'''
    self.last_name.send_keys("Test Automation Last Name")
    self.email.send_keys("a@b.com")
    self.password.send_keys("password")
    self.submit.click()
    self.first_name_error_message = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_required_error))
    )
    for first_name_required_message in self.first_name_error_message:
        first_name_message = first_name_required_message.text.replace("\n", ":")
        # print(first_name_message)
        # print(first_name_message[first_name_message.find(":") + 1:])
    assert first_name_message[first_name_message.find(":") + 1:] == "First name is required."
    sleep(1)
    self.last_name.clear()
    self.first_name.click()
    self.first_name.send_keys("Test Automation First Name ")
    self.submit.click()
    self.last_name_error_message = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_required_error)))

    for last_name_required_message in self.last_name_error_message:
        last_name_message = last_name_required_message.text.replace("\n", ":")
        assert last_name_message[last_name_message.find(":") + 1:] == "Last name is required."

    self.email.clear()
    self.last_name.click()
    self.last_name.send_keys("Test Automation Last Name ")
    self.submit.click()
    self.email_error_message = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_required_error)))

    for email_required_message in self.email_error_message:
        email_message = email_required_message.text.replace("\n", ":")
        assert email_message[email_message.find(":") + 1:] == "Email address is required."

    self.password.clear()
    self.email.click()
    self.email.send_keys("your@email.com")
    self.submit.click()
    self.password_error_message = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, sel_required_error)))
    '''only way i could assert it '''
    for password_required_message in self.password_error_message:
        password_message = password_required_message.text.replace("\n", " ")
        assert password_message[password_message.find("d") + 1:]\
                                                .replace(" ", "")  == "passwordisrequired."

    self.password.click()
    self.password.send_keys("something123$")
    self.submit.click()
```